# count numbers in file using BASH script

Tags: bash, shell

i have file with the following data records:

```
0.005
0.027
0.352
1.005
0.117
0.752
```

I'm trying to read the file using bash line by line and count the numbers into 3 groups:

```
if [($num < 0.2)] then min++
if [($num > 0.2) && ($num < 1)] then med++
if [($num > 1)] then max++
```

At the end I need to print out the 3 variable to file which count all the records.
Any idea how to read the file in bash and manipulating it using float in bash?

Comment: Since bash does not have floating point arithmetic, I suggest to use a different language, because you would have to revert to a tool like `bc` for the calculations, which is a bit cumbersome. For instance, the Z-Shell is a bit similar to bash, so it is easy to switch from bash to zsh, and zsh can do float. Of course lanuages like Perl, Python or Ruby would work equally well.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, bash doesn't like floating numbers very much; however, you may use other text processing tools like `awk`:

```
awk '{if($0 < 0.2)min++; else if($0 < 1)med++; else max++;} END {print min, med, max;}' file.txt
```

Also please note that your algorithm doesn't handle numbers exactly at 0.2 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with `bash` by all means, possible workaround will
be to multiply the numbers by 1,000 (or whatever appropriate) and treat
them as integers. How about:

```
while read -r x; do
    num=$((10#$(printf "%.3f" "$x" | tr -d ".")))
#   echo "$num"
    (( num < 200 )) && (( min++ ))
    (( num > 200 && num < 1000 )) && (( med++ ))
    (( num > 1000 )) && (( max++ ))
done < "data.txt"
printf "min=%d med=%d max=%d\n" "$min" "$med" "$max"
```

As @dibery comments, you need to decide how to handle exact 0.2 and 1.